# Pandas DataReader TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, finance, yahoo

So essentially I have been trying to use the DataReader function but to no avail.

I have imported all the relevant things in my code but everytime I use the DataReader function, I get a TypeError:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf

start_date = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end_date = dt.datetime(2021, 1, 1)

aapl_df = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'Yahoo', start=start_date, end=end_date)
```

For this I get this error:TypeError: download() got multiple values for argument 'start'

When I try this code instead:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-06-14')

df = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
df.tail(10)
```

I get the output :

[***100%%****]  1 of 1 completed

1 Failed download:
['AAPL']: ValueError("time data 'yahoo' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'")

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

here, but the yahoo data returning null

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import pytz
import yfinance as yf

tz = pytz.timezone("America/New_York") 
start_date = tz.localize(dt(2022,1,1))
end_date = tz.localize(dt(2022,6,14))
df = yf.download(['AAPL', 'yahoo'], start=start_date, end=end_date, auto_adjust=True)
df
```

Comment: 1 Failed download:
['YAHOO']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')
I got the response above

Comment: yes, i could not find it here https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch, maybe its really delisted